# Peak detection with the web audio API?

Tags: javascript, web, html5-audio, web-audio-api

TL;DR - I want to use Javascript to detect every click in a drummer's click track (an mp3 with only beats in it) and then replace these with .wav samples of a different click sound. The drummer click track is not in constant time, so I can't simply detect the BPM and replace samples from that.

I have a task I'd like to achieve with Javascript and the web audio API, but I'm not sure if it's actually possible using either of these....

Basically I regularly use recorded backing tracks for songs and I replace the default click track (the metronome track that a drummer plays along to) with custom click samples (one .wav sample for the first beat of a bar and another sample for the remaining beats in any given bar). Annoyingly many of these drummer click tracks are not in constant time - so do not have a constant BPM from start to finish.

I want to detect every click in a click track (every peak soundwave) and then replace these with the .wav samples, and download the final file as a MP3. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in way to do this in WebAudio.  You will have to implement your peak detector using a [`ScriptProcessorNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScriptProcessorNode) or [`AudioWorkletNode`](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/12/audio-worklet#registration_and_instantiation).  Once you have the location of each peak, you can then schedule your replacement clicks to start playing at the click times.  With an [`OfflineAudioContext`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OfflineAudioContext), you can get the resulting PCM result.  To get a compressed version (probably not mp3), I think you need to use a [`MediaRecorder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder).

Comment: Thanks. I've looked into this further and am wondering if this would be much easier in another language like Python. It seems this is stretching the current capabilities of JS.